# Constructing element which does not belong to a set

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

If $A$ is an arbitrary set, is it possible to *construct* an element $a\not\in A$ without the use of the Axiom of Regularity?

- It is clear that such $a$ exists (else $A$ would be the set of all
  sets), but this is not an explicit construction.
- Under assumption of the Axiom of Regularity, one could choose $a=A$.

To give more context, I'm starting with a family $\{X_i\mid i\in I\}$ of non-empty sets, and would like to find a sequence $\langle y_i \rangle_{i\in I}$ such that $y_i\not\in X_i$ for each $i\in I$, without using the Axiom of Choice and the Axiom of Regularity.

Comment: What exactly does "construct" mean? It's not entirely clear to me what sentence exactly you're asking about here. For example, are you asking whether there is a single formula $\varphi(x,y)$ in the language of set theory such that $\mathsf{ZF-Reg}$ proves "For every $x$ there is exactly one $y$ satisfying $\varphi(x,y)$, and for this $y$ we have $y\not\in x$"? Or something else?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yes, exactly!

Comment: I hate this question. It's been asked to death, but it's hard to locate, so it's never obvious where the duplicates are.

Comment: Your question is **literally** "is it possible in ZF-Reg that the set of all sets exists", and when you read it like that, it should be obvious how to answer it.

Comment: Well, the answer seems obvious now, and I was kind of convinced that there should be a corresponding construction, but I was missing the right idea... Excuse me, sir.

Comment: I've put a duplicate that is itself a duplicate, there are probably many others as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not be constructive enough, but there exists an element in the [Hartogs ordinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartogs_number) of $A$ that is not a member of $A$. Otherwise it would be a subset of $A$, a contradiction (there can be no injection from the Hartogs ordinal into $A$).

Comment: @NoahSchweber I've made an edit, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Note that you can make this a bit more explicit by observing that there is a **unique least** such element.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Indeed, it can be well-ordered. I have been away from set theory for too long:)

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

Comment: @Zuy No problem:)

Answer (score 2):

Here's one observation *(which is essentially the same as Tesla Daybreak's answer)*:

$\mathsf{ZF-Reg}$ is strong enough to prove that no set contains every ordinal. Now given a set $x$, let $y$ be the least ordinal not in $x$; regardless of whether regularity holds in the universe, the ordinals themselves are well-ordered as usual. This is totally explicit and pins down $y$ uniquely in terms of $x$.